# install_requires in setup.py depending on installed Python version

Tags: python, setuptools

My setup.py looks something like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    [...]
    install_requires=['gevent', 'ssl', 'configobj', 'simplejson', 'mechanize'],
    [...]
)
```

Under Python 2.6 (or higher) the installation of the ssl module fails with:

```
ValueError: This extension should not be used with Python 2.6 or later (already built in), and has not been tested with Python 2.3.4 or earlier.
```

Is there a standard way to define dependencies only for specific python versions? Of course I could do it with `if float(sys.version[:3]) < 2.6:` but maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: i cannot find install_requires as an argument to distutils.core.setup it seems left over from setuptools. http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.setup

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just a list, so somewhere above you have to conditionally build a list.
Something like to following is commonly done.

```
import sys

if sys.version_info < (2 , 6):
    REQUIRES = ['gevent', 'ssl', 'configobj', 'simplejson', 'mechanize'],
else:
    REQUIRES = ['gevent', 'configobj', 'simplejson', 'mechanize'],

setup(
# [...]
    install_requires=REQUIRES,
# [...]
)
```

Comment: There is now a better way, described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32643122/3565696)