# install_requires based on python version

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, distribute, install-requires

I have a module that works both on python 2 and python 3. In Python<3.2 I would like to install a specific package as a dependency. For Python>=3.2.

Something like:

```
 install_requires=[
    "threadpool >= 1.2.7 if python_version < 3.2.0",
 ],
```

How can one make that?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use [environment markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers):

```
install_requires=[
    'threadpool >= 1.2.7; python_version < "3.2.0"',
]
```

Setuptools specific usage is detailed in their [documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#platform-specific-dependencies). The syntax shown above requires setuptools v36.2+ [(change log)](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v36-2-0).

Comment: Don't omit the quotation marks around the python version number.

Answer (score 8):

This has been discussed [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2009-July/012826.html), it would appear the recommend way is to test for the Python version inside your `setup.py` using `sys.version_info`;

```
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3,2):
    install_requires = ["threadpool >= 1.2.7"]
else:
    install_requires = ["threadpool >= 1.2.3"]

setup(..., install_requires=install_requires)
```

Comment: This solution is fragile with many combinations of `pip` and `wheel` packages.  When pip builds wheels on your behalf, the computed install_requires list is written in the wheel metadata and then the cached wheel might be used on a different Python version.

Comment: Thanks.  This used to work for me, then stopped.  With your comment I was able to figure out it was because I recently changed my publish command to `bdist_wheel`.

Comment: It will not generate the correct package metadata this way.  **Avoid**.