# Specifying additional dependencies in setup.py script based on implementation (PyPy / CPython support)

Tags: python, setup.py, cpython, pypy

## Preface

I have a package with [PyPy](https://pypy.org/) support and for [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython) users it has `mypy` as an additional dependency which I specify as

```
import platform

from setuptools import setup
...
install_requires = [...]
if platform.python_implementation() != 'PyPy':
    install_requires.append('mypy>=0.630')
setup(...,
      install_requires=install_requires)
```

and locally it works fine, but when I create [source distribution](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#creating-a-source-distribution) via CPython like

```
> python setup.py sdist
```

and try to install it via PyPy

```
> pypy3 -m pip install path/to/package.tar.gz
```

it tries to install `mypy` (and fails since `mypy` uses CPython-specific packages), so it looks like dependencies are taken for CPython version (for which distribution was created).

## Problem

How can I specify dependencies and create source distribution once so it will work for both CPython & PyPy versions (and upload to PyPI afterwards)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current script tests the platform at build time, and not at install time.

What you need to use is not the `platform` module, but *environment markers* defined in [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers):

```
from setuptools import setup
...
install_requires = [...,
                    'mypy>=0.630; implementation_name != "PyPy"']
setup(...,
      install_requires=install_requires)
```

---

References:

- [install_requires based on python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082091/install-requires-based-on-python-version)
- [Building and Distributing Packages with Setuptools — setuptools 40.5.0 documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-platform-specific-dependencies)