# Setuptools, pip, virtualenv and windows

Tags: python, django, pip

I am working on a Windows system with limited download access.  My workaround is to download an app into a local folder.  Then in the virtualenv I use *pip install -e download folder* to install.  For instance, *pip install -e c:\django\test_virtualenv\South-0.8.4* and South is installed in the virtual environment.

In the virtualenv I am trying to install *django-user-accounts*, using the same method.  Unfortunately, this app has two dependencies listed in setup.py, namely, "django-appconf>=0.6", "pytz>=2013.9".  You can see these in the **install_requires** section in the setup.py file.

I was unable to redirect to a local folder such as *c:\download\django-appconf*

This lead to the question whether arguments were available when using *install_required* (part of setuptools).  [install_requires in setup.py depending on installed Python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080646/install-requires-in-setup-py-depending-on-installed-python-version) points out install_requires takes just a list.

In http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies the text talks about "limited network access" and "manually download all the eggs to a single directory".  This doc also suggests using *easy_install* with the -f option.

I have a neat system operational at the moment using *pip* and I am asking if anyone has found a way to redirect the downloading of dependencies from a local folder, no access to network resources for download.

Tommy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-to-pip-install-packages-according-to-requirements-txt-from-a-local-directory

Comment: Thank you anuragal.  That link answers my question.