# How to format Install requires line for json

Tags: json, python-2.7, install-requires

I have an info.json file with the line:

```
"install_requires"   : {""   : []},
```

Assuming that this is where I put packages that my program relies on, how would I format it if I want it to rely on

```
python-redmine
```

version 0.8.3

Would it possibly be

```
"install_requires"   : {"python-redmine"   : [0.8.3]},
```

Comment: I guess your question is already solved with this question 
[Refer this stack overflow question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080646/install-requires-in-setup-py-depending-on-installed-python-version

Comment: I looked into python setup.py, but it looks like the formatting is slightly different and I was hoping someone would be able to provide exactly how it should be formatted in json. (I'm not too familiar with json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

`"install_requires" : {"":["python-redmine==0.8.3"]},`